# How to connect to MongoDB using php on IIS

Tags: php, mongodb, iis

I have an IIS install (the one that comes with windows server 2016) with a working PHP 7.2 install.

I downloaded the `php_mongodb.dll` from here http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.5.2/windows   (I grabbed the 7.2 x64 'thread safe' version -- matter?)

I copied the dll into the php extensions folder: `C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\ext`

I then added `extension=php_mongodb.dll` to the php.ini file located at `C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\`

I then restarted IIS (well, the entire system)

I can then run a `phpinfo()` and the results do not included the word "mongo".

I also try running `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` and the results do not include the word 'mongo'.

I further try running some of the options here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.connecting.php and recieve server errors in the browser.

... so, how can I get a php->mongodb connection?

(alternately, what I'm ultimately trying to do is connect a javascript SPA to a mongodb back end...  are there other options than going through a php intermediary? -- it's an internal app, so security isn't the fearsome beast it would normally be)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the exact version of the dll you download matters.  I needed the x86 non-thread-safe version for some reason.

Still can't get a connection, but at least it's in the list of loaded extensions.

Answer (score 0):

try out all the possible files. atleast one may work i downloaded like 15 or 16 for my wamp 64 bit none worked.then i tried 7 versions in iis and finallly one worked. php version,build,archetecture all matters.